# Google Play Console - How do I resubmit an app release that's been rejected due to icon?

Tags: android, google-play

My app was rejected due to logo, which I updated. There was a save button which turned blue, I clicked it. now app status from "rejected" to showing "ready to send for review". But I can not understand how to send it for review?

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the issue for my release (missing description), I actually had to go to "Publishing Overview" and from there was able to find the button "Send for review" to submit the newest release.